# Blinking an arbitrary number of LEDs in succession

Tags: microcontroller, led

I've recently come across a problem that I feel should be nearly trivial, but for the life of me I can't figure out how it would be done. Basically all I want is a series of LEDs that will light up like dominoes. Essentially just looking for some way of triggering the next LED really.

This would be a pretty trivial problem with an Arduino and a relatively small number of LEDs (as many LEDs as pins), but I'm really looking for a way to put together a few dozen of these. I would prefer a solution that works without a microcontroller, but if I can use one microcontroller for a semi-arbitrary number of LEDs I would be more than happy.

Comment: shift registers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cascaded 4017 decade counters, pulsed by a single 555 timer. Each pulse makes the 4017 light the next one in sequence, which is then passed onto the next 4017, etc.
[image]

Comment: Awesome! I had never heard of decade counters before, but this looks perfect. I've having a little trouble wrapping my head around how exactly chaining them works though. Could you potentially add a little high level explanation for that?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus see http://www.aaroncake.net/forum/uploaded/Audioguru/2011626114852_cascaded%204017s-2.PNG for the full explanation.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus and by duplicating the left side multiple times (with pin 11 connecting to more and circuits) this can be expanded beyond 18 leds.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but why would the final pin freeze if we're still counting? My intuition is that the AND gate would just mean that when the first decade counter goes through a single cycle it increments the second decade counter and so on. I have a feeling that I'm wrong about this but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Ohwait, it's also wired up to the clock enable isn't it? So in general the last counting pin should be wired to the clock enable of its own decade timer, and the RESET of the next decade counter, its inverse sent to the clock enable of the next counter in the chain, and then it should be AND'd with the 555 timer to go the the clock pin of the next counter in the loop. Good to know this will generalize to a loop though.

Comment: This circuit will only light 1 LED at a time. When @SlaterTyranus says, "light up like dominoes" I interpret that to mean each clock tick lights the next LED and all the previous LEDs stay lit. In order to achieve this you want to use shift registers.

Comment: @jwygralak67 Ah, I probably should have been more explicit then, this is what I meant.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus ah, i assumed dominos as only one moving at a time. There are johnson counters that do that. Like 0001 -> 0011 -> 0111 -> 1111 -> 1110 -> 1100 etc.

Answer (score 7):

Look for individually addressable LED strips, a k a digital LED strips, such as [this one from eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1M-30LED-5050-SMD-WS2811-Individually-Addressable-Digital-LED-Dream-Color-Strip-/251257403197?pt=US_Car_Lighting&hash=item3a801bb73d) (*$15.99 including international shipping*):

[image: LED strip].

Adafruit also offers a [similar product](http://www.adafruit.com/products/306) (*$29.95*).

Such strips have a multitude of separate serializable LED controller ICs such as the [WS2811](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf) or the [Solarbotics LPD8806](https://solarbotics.com/download.php?file=1889) built in, which can control individual RGB LEDs.

All you need to do is send the appropriate serial data for each LED, to light it up to your requirements. This includes lighting them like dominos as mentioned in the question. Adafruit has a [tutorial on this](http://learn.adafruit.com/digital-led-strip/wiring).

A microcontroller will be needed to control the strip, but as the entire strip is controlled serially, with each LED's controller IC daisy-chained to the next, you will not need a large number of GPIO pins to control this.

Of course, you could fabricate your own solution using serializable LED controller ICs such as mentioned above, and your own LEDs.

Comment: This looks cool, but I feel like using a pre-built solution is kind of a copout.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus That's why I provided the links to some suitable controller ICs as well :-)