# clarification on a particular 555 implementation for 4017 johnson counters

Tags: 555, logic-gates, counter

I'm trying to build a 13 count johnson ring counter (which flashes LEDs sequentially 1 thru 13 and then repeats), and I found [this circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/77570/blinking-an-arbitrary-number-of-leds-in-succession) which looks perfect:
[image: 4017 johnson counter]

I assembled it with an extra LED on the 555's output pin. Oddly, when I apply power, this LED stays solid on, while none of the outputs of the 4017 are lit. In trying to troubleshoot this, I noticed that the wiring of the 555 differs from all of the standard implementations described on wikipedia (astable, monostable & bistable). 
QUESTIONS:

1. Does anyone know if this is a reasonable way to use a 555? The commenters on the aforementioned post seemed to think it was.
2. Otherwise, if you see it to be faulty, can you suggest an appropriate fix for this circuit? I tried a normal astable setup and got nothing, but I have to admit that my understanding of what the AND gates are doing is too foggy to know if this should work.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Edit: discovered a loose ground to the breadboard with the LEDs. Plugged this in, and now I see that a few of the LEDS are lit -- flickering & different brightnesses -- mostly on the second 4017. Totally stumped.

Comment: what value are you using for that anonymous cap in the diagram bottom right? I'm not sure what it should be doing, but a large enough value might prevent the 4017s from clocking?

Comment: @user44635 It's a 100nF, value stuck between the two diodes, up and down.

Comment: The schematics would be much easier to read if the pin names were also there.

Comment: Instead of using this circuit which you don't fully understand, build the logic for johnson counter with discrete D- flip flops.

Comment: @G Math 100nF ! that's a hellauv big value. What's it's supposed to do???

Comment: @user44635  I was hoping you could tell me that! :D  I tried putting a .01uF cap on it and got the same behavior.

Comment: There is a diode there after the output pin of the 555,that seems to be misplaced.The other on the far right looks the same.Have you checked them?

Comment: I find it odd that the circuitsis using a 12 volt supply for LEDs which normally use 3v. Maybe try it with a 5v or even 3v power source and see if it changes it's behaviour.